# Click on span link to view more content and save the full content to HTML casperjs

Tags: casperjs

I have a link with many span tags. When user clicks on these span links the whole content will appear.

I tried to write [casperjs](/questions/tagged/casperjs) script to click these span links and save the link to HTML file with full comments will be saved in the HTML file.

My script can save these short comments but can't save the full comments of users. Any advice?

```
casper.start('http://www.news.google.com/ABC.html',function(){
});
casper.then(function(){
    if(this.exists('span.tr308915699')){
       this.echo('this element exists');
       this.click('span.tr308915699');
    }
});
//Script to save to the HTML file
casper.waitForSelectorTextChange("div#review_308915699", function(){
    fs.write(save, this.getHTML(), 'w');
});
casper.run(function(){
 this.echo('done').exit();
});
```

Comment: So, the span element exists after clicking on it, its text changes. Are you sure that you need to check for text change? Maybe the comments are somewhere else. Have you tried simply waiting as static amount of time? Are the comments maybe in an iframe? I'm not familiar with that site and you haven't described how it should behave.

Comment: Thanks your concern, ArtjomB, these spans look like the more link on many sites, when you click on this more link, the whole content will be appeared. The content is in the  tag "span.entry p".

Comment: Please add the necessary markup to your question.

Comment: Hi everyone, I fixed this script, just added one more line, `this.click('span.tr308915699');`. I tried to change this script with `this.mouse.doubleclick('span.tr308915699');` but the result is not the one that I expected. Thanks.